# hudson to build only changed project

Tags: hudson, jobs

I have a requirement to build only changed project in hudson. We have out repository structure as

Projects/

------- Project A/src

------- Project B/src

------- Project C/src

We have arount 100+ indipendent projects in

I have a job configured in hudson which monitors the entire projects folder for changes (svn update).

What I'm trying to achieve is to build only the project which gets changed by passing the project name as argument for my build script
like ..... ant Project B ( upon changes in projectB). Is this feasible? Please guide me through.

Thanks

Comment: Why not creating 3 different projects in Hudson?

Comment: As siad we have 100+ proejects :(

Comment: Are those maven projects?

Comment: Nope, we use Ant. we have a master build script which can build all or a single project. I would like to read the project name from hudson changelog and pass it to build script. Sorry for not being so clear in my question.

Comment: Is there a way I can read porject name from hudson (svn) change log. Please help

Comment: Any thoughts? I still couldn't able to break it. Pls, guide